# How Can I repeat this program

Tags: python

still, an absolute beginner didn't find a proper way to make this repeat I need to repeat this program without for loop I just need to go to start of program once and output is printed

```
    dic = {10200:"Homagama" , 10206:"Pitipana" , 10101:"Athurugiriya" , }
a = input("Enter Postal Code:")

if int(a) in dic:
    print(dic[int(a)])

else:
    print("Not in our DB")
```

Comment: what's the problem with loop? put everything inside while loop and all the code will be executed repeatedly.

Comment: Would a `while` loop be fine or are you trying to do this without any kind of loop? And when should it stop the repetition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not want to use a loop you can go for a recursive function (which is a function which basically calls itself at a certain point of time)

```
def func():
        dic = {10200:"Homagama" , 10206:"Pitipana" , 10101:"Athurugiriya"}
        a = input("Enter Postal Code:")
        if int(a) in dic:
            print(dic[int(a)])
        else:
            print("Not in our DB")
        if condition_of_repeating:# when you want to repeat
            func()
func()
```

Although a simple loop is definetly suggested.